# Is there a way to download a video's audio in mp3 using flashgot without using a youtube-to-mp3 converter?

Tags: video, youtube, mp3, convert, webm

Now, I know that there are tons of questions about this topic but not quite this one as it specifically asks about flashgot.

The unique trait of flashgot is that it works with every website (not like other youtube-oriented apps) so I just want to know if there is a direct way of downloading the audio only in mp3 using flashgot, if not then a link to a nice how-to on converting webm audio to mp3 using terminal would be nice.

I'm running 16.04 LTS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### To convert

I use `ffmpeg` [[1]](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1935582):

```
 ffmpeg -i input.webm -acodec libmp3lame -aq 4 output.mp3
```

- `-i`: input file
- `-acodec`: audio codec

  - LAME is a high quality MPEG Audio Layer III (MP3) encoder licensed under the LGPL. [[2]](http://lame.sourceforge.net/).
- `aq`: audio quality [[3]](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/FFmpeg)

  - aq 4 = 128 kb/s
  - aq 5 = 160 kb/s
  - aq 6 = 192 kb/s
  - aq 7 = 224 kb/s
  - aq 8 = 256 kb/s

#### To download

I use `youtube-dl` it support a lot of sites, you can use `-F` switch to get a list of available formats, if there was an only audio format available you can only download that.

```
$ youtube-dl --list-extractors | wc -l
1035
```

Means it support 1035 sites.

Comment: if you can clarify a bit more on -acodec and aq .. I'm sorry I'm very new to ubuntu

Comment: Updated the answer... you can accept it if you think it was helpful to you ;)